# Where can I find "Google cloud platform user account Id"

Tags: google, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to create an account to new google vision api to possibly integrate its service in the app http://www.openbricks.io I am working on.

But the form to have access to this new api ask for an account on google cloud platform, it is my case, 
but also a mystical Google cloud platform user account Id, I cannot find no where google cloud help is a real maze and to have support we need to pay.

Is anyone using Google cloud platform ? and know how to get this id ?

Answer (score 1):

Home -> Dashboard. Look in the "Project" section of the main window pane.